# PDF to XML using adobe c#

Tags: c#, adobe, pdf-extraction

I have adobe license version that (adobe acrobat) can help me to export PDF to XML.
Can i do same thing with c#? (I tried other options like spreadsheet, Images and other but i want to do Convert it into XML)

Thank you

Comment: What is in the PDF and how should the extracted data look like in XML?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes. Have lot's pdf those need to convert into XML. Currently I am using XML export feature of Adobe acrobat. but want to it with c#

Comment: @KlausGütter it have lot's of table data form